# Working with multiple repositories in one ViewModel on kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Tell me, please, how to make it more correct so that the ViewModel supports working with the desired repository, depending on the viewmodel's parameter? Android application should display a list of requests, requests are of different types. I want to use one fragment for request of different types and in one model I want universally work with a repository that will pull out requests of the required type from the database (Room).

I made a common interface for repositories:

```
interface RequestRepository<T> {

    fun getRequests(): LiveData<List<T>>

    fun getRequestById(requestId: String): LiveData<T>

    suspend fun insertRequests(requests: List<T>)

    suspend fun deleteRequest(request: T)

    suspend fun deleteAllRequests()

}
```

This is one of the repositories:

```
class PaymentRequestRepository private constructor(private val paymentRequestDao: PaymentRequestDao) : RequestRepository<PaymentRequest> {

    override fun getRequests() = paymentRequestDao.getRequests()

    override fun getRequestById(requestId: String) = paymentRequestDao.getRequestById(requestId)

    override suspend fun insertRequests(requests: List<PaymentRequest>) {
        paymentRequestDao.deleteAll()
        paymentRequestDao.insertAll(requests)
    }

    override suspend fun deleteRequest(request: PaymentRequest) = paymentRequestDao.delete(request)

    override suspend fun deleteAllRequests() = paymentRequestDao.deleteAll()

    companion object {

        // For Singleton instantiation
        @Volatile private var instance: PaymentRequestRepository? = null

        fun getInstance(paymentRequestDao: PaymentRequestDao) =
            instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance ?: PaymentRequestRepository(paymentRequestDao).also { instance = it }
            }
    }

}
```

How in the ViewModel to work with the necessary repository depending on the type of request?

```
class RequestListViewModel(application: Application, val requestType: RequestType): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    //lateinit var paymentRequestRepository: PaymentRequestRepository
    //lateinit var serviceRequestRepository: ServiceRequestRepository
    lateinit var requestRepository: RequestRepository<BaseRequestDao<Request>>

    ...

    init {
        val database = AgreementsDatabase.getDatabase(application)

        when (requestType) {
            RequestType.MONEY -> {
                val paymentRequestDao = database.paymentRequestsDao()
                requestRepository = PaymentRequestRepository.getInstance(paymentRequestDao)
            }
            RequestType.SERVICE -> {
                val serviceRequestDao = database.serviceRequestsDao()
                requestRepository = ServiceRequestRepository.getInstance(serviceRequestDao)
            }
            RequestType.DELIVERY -> {
                val deliveryRequestsDao = database.deliveryRequestsDao()
                requestRepository = DeliveryRequestRepository.getInstance(deliveryRequestsDao)
            }
        }
        _requests = requestRepository.getRequests()

        updateRequests();
    }
}
```

** When creating a repository, I get a type mismatch error: **

**requestRepository = PaymentRequestRepository.getInstance(paymentRequestDao)**

Tell me how is this done correctly?

Comment: `lateinit var requestRepository: RequestRepository<BaseRequestDao<Request>>` This line is wrong probably. It should be something like `RequestRepository<Request>`. Also you could move that `when` statement stuff into a UseCase and set up the repository there. ViewModel doesn't need to care about setting up repositories for the data.

Comment: Thank you for this idea.
I will try to make a common interface for ViewModel and I will use a specific implementation of this interface depending on the parameter.